# Public free time server

Tags: time

I need to get the current datetime from a reliable source, because its likely that the local system time could be changed.

Is it possible to get this from an internet time server, one that has close to 100% uptime, preferably via a webservice method, something that is free, and I have to stress absolutely reliable?

I would hope an offering from Microsoft, or the organisation responsible for keeping global time.

Comment: you were hoping for a service that would provide Microsoft Time?

Comment: yeah, that's something like Moscow time - only global ;)

Comment: These are the two defaults that ship with XP Pro:
* time.windows.com
* time.nist.gov

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give a try to:

http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/

It has a pool of NTP servers which provides accurate time data.

NTP is a protocol so you can write easily a client to query the time.

Comment: Thanks, but I will use this as a last resort, what I am really interested in is an exposed webservice.

Comment: Synching time over a webservice seems like a tremendously bad idea. NTP is a well established protocol that was specifically developed to deliver accurate results.

Comment: This is exactly what NTP is for. You send it a request via UDP and receive a response with time information. It's an old, reliable and robust protocol and most NTP servers have very high availability. In addition to that, you can query multiple NTP servers in case 1 is down.

Comment: Moreover, if NTP could suffer about network latency, imagine a webservice request with all that SOAP glory

Comment: So... this exact Pool.ntp.org/zone - this is the right server to use?

Comment: Ok I am going to follow your recommendations, and forget about the web service approach.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much every web server will tell you the time.

> $ *telnet www.google.com 80*
>   Trying 74.125.224.52...
>   Connected to www.google.com.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   *GET /moose HTTP/1.0*
>   *Host: www.google.com*
>   
>   HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   **Date: Fri, 26 Aug 2011 08:58:28 GMT**
>   Server: sffe
>   Content-Length: 11793
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

[www.pool.ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/) is a web page that guides you through which pool of servers you should use (which is closer to you). The NTP pool contains large number of servers, so it's very unlikely that you'll stumble upon on a non-working server; very recommended. HTTP will never deliver precise time like NTP.